# Codenameone: start() Method not always called on resume of app

Tags: codenameone

Did anyone ever discovered, that the start-Methode of the Codenameone-App is not always called when resuming the app? Sometime when I resume my CN1 App when it is paused before - especially when the last run is some hours ago - the start-App ist not called.

Comment: On which platform?
If `stop()` was invoked `start()` must be invoked otherwise it's a bug/regression and we need a test case for that

Comment: Oh sorry - I forgot this information: It only happens on my iPhone X (currently with the newest iOS-Version - but I had this with previous iOS versions as well). I never saw it on my iPad (also with the newest iOS-version).

Comment: And it occurs on my iPhone only sometimes - not always. I did not recognize a rule yet.

Comment: Is it possible this is a recent regression? From this week?
We had some complaints about the current release and we're looking into them.

Comment: I can see this since months - so I don't believe it's a recent regression.

Comment: Do you have a way to consistently reproduce that? If so we need an issue with an exact test case and full device/OS details.

Comment: I'm sorry - but I don't know how to reproduce it. It happens randomly (for me).

Comment: Does it happen with a specific configuration at any regularity. If you can provide any hints about your environment and what this might be it could help.

Comment: Hmmm - iOS 13..4.1 - but also seen with iOS 12. It happens only on iPhone - not on iPad. My App logs every call of the start()-Methode - and sometimes it‘s not logged. Because in the App a data-sync with the dropbox is called with an infinite progress indicator on start() it‘s obvious when the start method is not called. I don‘t know which information else could be helpfull for you.

Comment: Is it possible the infinite progress call is made from the start method?

Comment: Yes - that's true. Do you think this might lead to this behaviour? But than I would see some entries in the Log-File which are written before shwoing the infinite progress - and in the cases I described above no Log ist written.

Comment: Then we'll need some way to reproduce this issue, even if it reproduces sporadically.

Comment: Today I had this case again - no log-Entry of the start() method was written when I resumed the App. Don't know why.